What weight on a still stepper motor?
I want to make an extending leg that uses a stepper motor at the bottom, spindle upwards. With a screw thread at the end of the spindle. The motor will rotate to push up a nut which will push up the leg. The weight it will push up will probably be about 7kg. However once adjusted I expect the weight to be about 130kg. Question is what stepper motor could stand this weight and I guess also push up 7kg?

I think it would be bad practice to apply this much thrust load to the stepper bearings. You will want a separate thrust bearing. The stepper also will likely need a gear reduction or a very fine screw to have sufficient torque.

It looks like I found what I was looking for in a linear actuator.
https://share.temu.com/cTUa8ElFOMA

A worm gear could help to reduce the load on the motor. Then it would only be a question of the gear ratio.
